# @RequestMapping does not work on methods when I have annotated the controller

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have annotated the controller with a requestmapping. I also annotated the method with another requestmapping, however it doesn't seemed to get mapped. I am using **Spring 2.5.**

```
@RequestMapping("/animals")
@Controller
public class AnimalController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/tiger")
    public void doSomething(...) {..}
}
```

Shouldn't this give me the path /animals/tiger? I have these in the context config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

I only get a exception saying that it isn't mapped.

Comment: Have you added `@controller`?

Comment: @Karna Yes, forgot to copy.

Comment: Please check the logs when Spring is initialized and see if it parsed your controller and show the urls.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale Where do I find that?

Comment: Is your application configured to do logging using log4j like solution? If yes then check in that log. I believe this information is logged at DEBUG level so you would need to switch on that level.

Comment: see as well to what prefix you have mapped your DispatcherServlet.

Comment: @soulcheck I have checked that.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale I don't use any logging frameworks on the server yet.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the controller is loaded by spring

Comment: @ArunPJohny The controller is loaded, but the method is not mapped it seems. The other methods without the values attribute work.

Comment: Do you have `annotation driven` and `controller scan` lines in your configuration of `Spring MVC`?

Comment: @Mrusful Yes, it should be configured (after what I read) from the bean declarations above and I also have the component scan declaration. I get `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI /animals/tiger...` (from the top of my head)

Comment: Check `tomcat` logs, something went wrong at startup/configure. Which `servlet container` and `JRE` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the @Controller annotation above the class definition. But in addition to that you need to specify the type of Request. e.g. is is POST or GET. An example is shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "tiger", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Also, note that a forward slash is not needed before the String 'tiger'. This is automatic.

Comment: Note the changes to my comment.

Comment: OP doesn't need to specify `RequestMethod`. Like it is now, the mapping  will handle any http method.